# filter column with last 4 digits using restapi

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, filter, modern-experience

We have a column where the values are stored as '1002859817' and the Field Type is single line of text.

***The end goal here is to filter the column based on the last 4 digits i.e. '9817'***

Tried the options like substring and contains , However no results are returned

**Below is the query**:

```
var myQuery= "$select=QuoteNo";

        if(filterType!=="" && filterVal!==""){
            
            myQuery+="$&filter=substringof('"+filterVal+"','"+QuoteNo+"')";
        }   

        myQuery+="&$top=4999";
        myQuery+="&$orderby=ID desc";
```

**Filter**:

```
myQuery+="$&filter=substringof('"+filterVal+"','"+QuoteNo+"')";
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint REST API does not support `endswith`, [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#odata-query-operators-supported-in-the-sharepoint-rest-service).

If you want to filter using `substringof`, you can use your query like below:

```
<siteUrl>/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items?$select=QuoteNo&$filter=substringof('9817',QuoteNo)
```

No need to surround column name by `''`.

**Note**: This endpoint will return all the items which **contains** `9817` **anywhere** in `QuoteNo` column and **not only at the end**.

If you want to filter the items by "endwith" (last 4 digits) condition, you have to do that client side using JavaScript after fetching all items from list. For this you can use [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) method of JavaScript for string comparison inside loop in success.

---

**Update from comments**:

Here's working example of passing column name & value to filter dynamically. You can refer this code & make changes in your code accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/SPConnect/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="getListItems('ChildList')"> Get List Items</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getListItems(listName) {
        var columnName = "Title";
        var columnValue = "Child 1";

        var itemsEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=" + columnName + "&$filter=substringof('" + columnValue + "'," + columnName + ")";

        $.ajax({
            url: itemsEndpoint,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Remove `''` around column name. Also make sure you are adding that column in `$select`.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh , would give this a try , However the requirement here is the column name needs to be dynamic and so is the value and hence
myQuery+="$&filter=substringof('"+TextToFilter+"','"+ColumnName+"')";
Can you please validate if I'm doing it correctly?

Also not getting any errors

Comment: Refer code in updated answer. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh , I tried this , However it is also returning entries ending with 0280 , can we move the conversation to chat?

Comment: As I said in my answer, SharePoint REST API does not support `endswith`. and `substringof` is like "contains" search. It will return all items where `QuoteNo` contains `9817`. It is not possible to add filter based on last 4 digits (ending with).

Comment: In that case, first you have to fetch all items using REST API & then filter returned items based on your conditions/requirements. For this you can use [endsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) method of JavaScript for string comparison.

Comment: @Vivek, Ganesh Sanap is right, you should use the `substringof` REST filter to just narrow down the results to ones that _contain_ the number sequence you want, but then you are going to have to take those results and do additional filtering in JavaScript using `endsWith()` to get the ones that specifically _end_ with the sequence you want.  It's going to be a two-step process.

Comment: @GaneshSanap and Dylan Sure since I am getting the required values from substring , marking it as a solution :) Thanks for the help guys :)